# ng-pattern to check ng-minlength and prefix with 0 until length is short

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-pattern

In my text box it will allow only number (i can use type=number) and I have to fulfill 8 character length. I can do it using ng-minlength. But the range of the numbers may start from 4 digit and I don't want my users to write the extra 0 at the beginning if it is short from 8 character in length.

For example if the value is `2015`, then my expected value is to be as `00002015` in the textbox. So, the user need to write the additional 4 extra 0 before writing his actual value. It is not a productive way to data entry.

***My question is, is there any way I can automatically set the 0 in the prefix of the value in my textbox / ng-model variable after the user is typed his number? I can do it in the programmatic way using ng-change and ng-blur event, but i am seeking any automatic way***